# Regex for certain string and digit for time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

anyone can help me?
I have a string with format: `10 mins - 20 mins` OR `1 min - 10 mins` OR `10 mins - 1 hour` OR `10 mins - 1 hour 30 mins` OR `10 mins - 2 hours` OR `10 mins - 2 hours 30 mins`.
I wanna create a regex for all formats but I can't :disappointed: . Please help me, thanks a lot.

A regex possible with all above formats.

Comment: Regex is just a tool. _What problem_ do you want to solve using this tool?

Comment: yes, i wanna find regex to validate a column in my table when a record is created or updated.

Comment: Validate in which sense? That it contains _only_ the strings that you posted? Just put them in an array and check the presence - it is more robust, probably faster than regex and still quite concise (due to a small number of variants). Or you allow any valid range (so it can be `1 min - 2 mins` etc)? In this case regex is not the tool for the job. Could you clarify the question, please?

Comment: It's an interesting question but you need to clarify your requirements. Be clear and precise! Also, being new to SO you may not realise that informal language such as "wanna" is discouraged. Have a look at other questions, answers and comments to better understand language standards at SO.

Answer (score 0):

I might split on the dash first, then match out the components in each side using the same regular expression.

E.g.

```
"1 hour 10 mins - 3 hours".split(/\s+-\s+/, 2).map do |s| 
  s.scan(
    /
        \d+ \s+ mins
      | \d+ \s+ hour(?=s?)
      | \d+ \s+ hour(?=s?) 
        \s+ 
        \d+ \s+ min(?=s?)
    /x
  ) 
end
# => [["1 hour", "10 mins"], ["3 hour"]]

"1 hour 10 mins - 40 mins".split(/\s+-\s+/, 2).map do |s| 
  s.scan(
    /
        \d+ \s+ mins
      | \d+ \s+ hour(?=s?)
      | \d+ \s+ hour(?=s?) 
        \s+ 
        \d+ \s+ min(?=s?)
    /x
  ) 
end
# [["1 hour", "10 mins"], ["40 mins"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've assumed:

- every string contains only minutes (not hours) to the left of the minus sign; and
- hours, where present, are between 1 and 9.

These assumptions are consistent with the examples given in the question.

---

One can then use [String#match](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-match) and [MatchData#named_captures](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/MatchData.html#method-i-named_captures) with the regular expression

```
rgx = /(?<lmin>(?:[1-9]|[1-5]\d)) mins? \- (?:(?<hr>[1-9]) hours?(?: (?<rminwhr>\g<lmin>) mins?)?|(?<rminwohr>\g<lmin>) mins?)/
```

to extract the values of interest. Let's try it for the examples given in the question.

```
["10 mins - 20 mins",
 "1 min - 10 mins",
 "10 mins - 1 hour",
 "10 mins - 1 hour 30 mins",
 "10 mins - 2 hours",
 "10 mins - 2 hours 30 mins"].each do |str|
   m = str.match(rgx)
   puts str
   puts "str.match(rgx) = #{m.inspect}"
   puts "captures = #{m.named_captures}"
   puts
 end
```

displays the following.

```
10 mins - 20 mins
str.match(rgx) = #<MatchData "10 mins - 20 mins" lmin:"20" hr:nil rminwhr:nil rminwohr:"20">
captures = {"lmin"=>"20", "hr"=>nil, "rminwhr"=>nil, "rminwohr"=>"20"}

1 min - 10 mins
str.match(rgx) = #<MatchData "1 min - 10 mins" lmin:"10" hr:nil rminwhr:nil rminwohr:"10">
captures = {"lmin"=>"10", "hr"=>nil, "rminwhr"=>nil, "rminwohr"=>"10"}

10 mins - 1 hour
str.match(rgx) = #<MatchData "10 mins - 1 hour" lmin:"10" hr:"1" rminwhr:nil rminwohr:nil>
captures = {"lmin"=>"10", "hr"=>"1", "rminwhr"=>nil, "rminwohr"=>nil}

10 mins - 1 hour 30 mins
str.match(rgx) = #<MatchData "10 mins - 1 hour 30 mins" lmin:"30" hr:"1" rminwhr:"30" rminwohr:nil>
captures = {"lmin"=>"30", "hr"=>"1", "rminwhr"=>"30", "rminwohr"=>nil}

10 mins - 2 hours
str.match(rgx) = #<MatchData "10 mins - 2 hours" lmin:"10" hr:"2" rminwhr:nil rminwohr:nil>
captures = {"lmin"=>"10", "hr"=>"2", "rminwhr"=>nil, "rminwohr"=>nil}

10 mins - 2 hours 30 mins
str.match(rgx) = #<MatchData "10 mins - 2 hours 30 mins" lmin:"30" hr:"2" rminwhr:"30" rminwohr:nil>
captures = {"lmin"=>"30", "hr"=>"2", "rminwhr"=>"30", "rminwohr"=>nil}
```

`lmin` reads "minutes to left of minus sign"; `rminwhr` (`rminwohr`) reads "minutes to right of minus sign with (without) hours".

---

One can see a demonstration of the regular expression [here](https://regex101.com/r/ThzUmm/1). Hover the cursor over the regular expression to see an explanation of the function of each part of the expression. These results are shown for the PCRE regex engine but they are the same for Ruby's regex engine (Oniguruma).

---

We can write the regular expression in *free-spacing mode* to make it self-documenting.

```
/
(?<lmin>        # begin capture group 'lmin'
  (?:           # begin non-capture group
    [1-9]       # match a digit other than zero 
    |           # or
    [1-5]\d     # match a digit between 1 and 5, followed by a digit
  )             # end non-capture group
)               # end capture group 'lmin'
[ ]mins?        # match a space followed by 'min', 's' optional
[ ]\-[ ]        # match ' - '
(?:             # begin non-capture group
  (?<hr>        # begin capture group 'hr'
    [1-9]       # match a digit other than zero
  )             # end capture group 'hr'
  [ ]hours?     # match a space followed by 'hour', 's' optional
  (?:           # begin a non-capture group
    [ ]         # match a space
    (?<rminwhr> # begin capture group 'rminwhr'
      \g<lmin>  # invoke subexpression 'lmin'
    )           # end capture group 'rminwhr'
    [ ]mins?    # match a space followed by 'min', 's' optional
  )             # end non-capture group
  ?             # make the preceding non-capture group optional
  |             # or
  (?<rminwohr>  # begin capture group 'rminwohr'
    \g<lmin>    # invoke subexpression 'lmin'
  )             # end capture group 'rminwohr'
  [ ]mins?      # match a space followed by 'min', 's' optional
)               # end non-capture group
/x              # invoke free-spacing regex definition mode
```

`g<lmin>` causes the code used to create named capture group named `lmin` to be reused at that location. This is called a "subexpression" or "subrouting". For an explanation search for "Subexpression" in [Regexp](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Regexp.html). The use of subexpressions reduces the size of the expression, makes it easier to read and reduces the chances of errors, particularly if the expression is modified in future.

Notice that in free-spacing mode spaces that are intended to part of the expression must be protected in some way to prevent them from being stripped out before the expression is parsed. I've chosen to put each one in a character class, but there are other ways of doing that (for one, escaping the space character).